# why the setOnclicklistener is not working in a particular item of row in endlessrecyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to set an on-click event for a particular item in a row of endless recyclerview. I wrote on-click inside the adapter and implemented to the activity by using the interface.But my issue is that the on-click function is not working.

I have tried with the row position but it is not working.

```
 public interface ViewOnMapAdapterListener {

    void viewOnMapOnClick(ModelTripHistoryDetails data);

}



 @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        if (position >= getItemCount() - 1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener != null) {
            isLoading = true;
            loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }

        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LIST) {
            ((TripHolder) holder).bindData(tripDetailsList.get(position), position, viewOnMapAdapterListener);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //No else part needed as load holder doesn't bind any data
}

 void bindData(final ModelTripHistoryDetails tripDetais, final int position, final AdapterTripHistory.ViewOnMapAdapterListener viewOnMapAdapterListener) throws ParseException {

        try {

            setDatas(tripDetais);

            tvViewOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                        viewOnMapAdapterListener.viewOnMapOnClick(tripDetais);

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

> Activity

```
 private void initView() {
    tripDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    rvTripHistory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTripHistory);
    context = this;

    adapterTripHistory = new AdapterTripHistory(this, tripDetailsList, new AdapterTripHistory.ViewOnMapAdapterListener() {
        @Override
        public void viewOnMapOnClick(ModelTripHistoryDetails data) {
            Toast.makeText(TripHistoryActivity.this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    adapterTripHistory.setLoadMoreListener(new AdapterTripHistory.OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {

            rvTripHistory.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    index++;
                    loadMore(index);
                }
            });
            //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
            // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should share the related onClick implementation

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru I have shared the implementation

Comment: Are you sure that setting onClick implementation to ViewHolder which is parameter of  onBindViewHolder ?

Comment: I have implemented the onclick inside the bind() function(inside ViewHolder),which is called with the data,position and the listener from the onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you, to add logs inside every `try-catch` block. You are probably getting some exception inside `setDatas(tripDetais)` method and you never set listener to the view because of that exception.

Comment: Or be a modern programmer and attach a debugger

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to implement a Holder class that extends ViewHolder and implement View.OnClickListener(), something like this:

```
    public static  class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView someView;
    OnYourListener onYourListener;

    public Holder(@NonNull View itemView,OnYourListener onYourListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.onYourListener = onYourListener;
        someView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.some_view);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onYourListener.onYourClicked(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

and pass the activity that implement the interface to the adapter as the listener.
your adapter constructor should look something like this:

```
    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<somthing> arrayList, OnYourListener onYourListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.ArrayList = ArrayList;
    this.mOnYourListener = onYourListener;

}
```

and on createViewHolder you should pass the listener like so:

```
    @Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

  View layout = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
  Holder holder =new Holder(layout,mOnYourListener);
  return holder;
}
```

This way you can create a holder the way you want to and the onclick should  work